# Simple WHERE clause kills my query's performance

Tags: sql-server

I have this weird performance issue with a query and I'm trying to figure out why this happens. This is a simplified example of the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table1.status AS Status
FROM table1
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT DataID, MAX(VersionNum) as mVersion 
        FROM table1
        GROUP BY DataID 
    ) AS b 
    ON table1.DataID = b.DataID 
    AND table1.VersionNum = b.mVersion
INNER JOIN table2
    ON table1.table2ID = table2.ID
WHERE table2.field = @parameter
```

Table 1 consists of rows that sometimes have the same DataID, these each have a version number, I need to select the highest number from that set of rows.

Table 1 contains a certain ID that can be used to join with table2.
If I add a constraint from table2 and the parameter actually exists in table2 the query takes over a minute to complete, returning 10 rows.

If I add constraints for table1 there are no performance issues whatsoever, taking less than a second to complete.

I hope this is enough information, I'm really curious as to why this happens and how I can solve it.

EDIT: I must mention that if I remove the first inner join (to filter the max version), the performance drop is gone.

Comment: Do you have any indices, and if yes, what are they exactly?

Comment: So, are you using MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: What is the data type of `table2.field`, and what is the value of `%Parameter%`?

Comment: for table2, if I create the index to a new window it returns this:

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [table2_Index1] ON [table2] 

(

 [VolumeID] ASC,

 [DataID] ASC,

 [VersionNum] ASC,

 [Seq] ASC

)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: table2.field is an INT, and the value would be a 6-digit number

Comment: Adding that `WHERE` clause as part of the `JOIN` condition _may_ help, although I would have expected the query optimizer to be able to handle that one.  At minimum, you're going to want an index on table2 with those 2 columns (and probably in that order).

Answer (score 0):

I know the profiler should be able to handle all these cases, but I'm going to ask anyway...

Have you tried profiling any of the following:

- Converting the inner selection to a CTE?

> ```
>   WITH CTE_Versions AS (
>       SELECT DataID, MAX(VersionNum) as mVersion 
>       FROM t1
>       GROUP BY DataID 
>   )
>   SELECT DISTINCT t1.status AS Status
>   FROM t1
>   JOIN CTE_Versions AS b
>       ON t1.DataID = b.DataID 
>       AND t1.VersionNum = b.mVersion
>   JOIN table2
>       ON t1.table2ID = table2.ID
>   WHERE table2.field = @parameter
> ```

- Adding locking hints?

> ```
>   SELECT DISTINCT t1.status AS Status
>   FROM t1 with (nolock)
>   JOIN (
>           SELECT DataID, MAX(VersionNum) as mVersion 
>           FROM t1 with (nolock)
>           GROUP BY DataID 
>   ) AS b
>       ON t1.DataID = b.DataID 
>       AND t1.VersionNum = b.mVersion
>   JOIN table2 with (nolock)
>       ON t1.table2ID = table2.ID
>   WHERE table2.field = @parameter
> ```

- Moving the parameter into the join? (as per @X-Zero's comment)

> ```
>   SELECT DISTINCT t1.status AS Status
>   FROM t1
>   JOIN (
>           SELECT DataID, MAX(VersionNum) as mVersion 
>           FROM t1
>           GROUP BY DataID 
>   ) AS b
>       ON  t1.DataID = b.DataID 
>       AND t1.VersionNum = b.mVersion
>   JOIN table2
>       ON  t1.table2ID = table2.ID
>       AND table2.field = @parameter
> ```

I'd be interested to hear how those three (or a combination thereof) would go?